# How to exclude certain Enum type from stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections, java-stream

How can I exclude an enum named **CodesType** in this code ?

Code returns a list of objects of the **EventsData** class and I want to be able to skip one designated enum.

I would like to exclude an Enum named **CodesType**. By default it is added in the mapEvents variable which means that I would have to add some filtering there so that the Enum named **CodesType** is skipped. I just don't know how to implement correctly. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work `.filter(type -> type != CodesType)`.

You can also see in the code that I manually add two **EventsData** objects such as **CodesType** and **SupportType**. Therefore, I want to exclude this **CodesType** object that is added at the beginning so that a duplicate is not created. (It has to exist because the objects I add manually are created based on it, but it doesn't have to be retrieved so I want to exclude it).

```
private List < EventsData > getEvents() {
    final List < EventsData > eventsList = eventListStream.stream()
        .map(mapEvents)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    eventList.add(new EventsData("CodesType", getCodesType()));
    eventList.add(new EventsData("SupportType", getSupportType()));
    return eventList;
)
```

Comment: `.filter(type -> type != CodesType.class)` Side note: don’t use `.sorted(String::compareTo)` Use either, `.sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or just `.sorted()`. And don’t rely on the assumption that `Collectors.toList()` returns a mutable list. If you have to add elements afterwards, use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Comment: Sounds like you put this at the wrong location. You want to filter the stream of types, so it has to be `List<EventsData> eventsList = eventListStream.stream() .filter(type -> type != CodesType.class).map(mapEvents).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` I deduce from your code that `eventListStream` is some sort of collection of `Class<? extends Enum>`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
private List<EventsData> getEvents() {
    final List<EventsData> eventList = eventListStream.stream()
        .filter(type -> type != CodesType.class)
        .map(events -> new EventsData(events.getSimpleName(), getType(events)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    eventList.add(new EventsData("CodesType", getCodesType()));
    eventList.add(new EventsData("SupportType", getSupportType()));
    return eventList;
}

private String[] getType(Class<? extends Enum<?>> events) {
    return Arrays.stream(events.getEnumConstants())
        .map(Enum::name)
        .sorted()
        .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Instead of declaring a `Function` outside the Stream pipeline, I moved the complex part into a named method, which aligns with your already existing methods, `getCodesType()` and `getSupportType()`.

Instead of collecting into a mutable list, to add the predefined elements, you can also integrate them into the Stream pipeline:

```java
private List<EventsData> getEvents() {
    return Stream.concat(
        eventListStream.stream()
            .filter(type -> type != CodesType.class)
            .map(events -> new EventsData(events.getSimpleName(),getType(events))),
        Stream.of(new EventsData("CodesType", getCodesType()),
                  new EventsData("SupportType", getSupportType()))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `instanceof` for exemaple

```
.filter(type -> ! (type instanceof CodesType))
```

or, combination with `Predicates.not`, like this:

```
.filter(not(type -> type instanceof CodesType))
```

Additionally, enums can implement interfaces. So another thing that you can do is to add some sort of polymorphic behavior. For instance, instead of passing `<T extends Enum>` which is a rather primitive type, you can declare an interface with a more meaningful name:

```
public interface MySpecialEnum { // find a better name
    boolean allowsFeatureX(); // same here
}
```

Now, your special enums can implement this interface:

```
enum CodesType implements MySpecialEnum {
    A, B;

    @Override
    public boolean allowsFeatureX() {
        return false;
    }
}

enum SupportType implements MySpecialEnum {
    C, D;

    @Override
    public boolean allowsFeatureX() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of passing `< ? extends Enum >` you can use the type `MySpecialEnum`. Moreover, instead of filtering by `class` or using `instance of`, you'll have a cleaner solution:

```
.filter(MySpecialEnum::allowsFeatureX)
```

This will also allow you to add this flag/behavior for other "special" enums in the future.